# How to make sure every unique label's count number larger than a value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D array that contains labels beginning from 0. The goal is to make sure every unique label's count number is >= a constant (e.g. 10). If not, merge the nearest label into it until the count larger than 10.

Here's an example:

```
import random
import numpy as np

data = np.concatenate(([0]*5, [1]*10, [2]*15, [3]*10, [4]*12, [5]*5))
random.Random(4).shuffle(data)
print(data)
```

```
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 4, 1, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1,
       5, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0,
       2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2])
```

The logic should be like this:

Beginning from label `0`, because the count of `0` is 5 (< 10), merging `1` with 0 by replacing `1` with `0`. Then label `0` has enough counts (15).

Then, continue to the next label `2` which meets the condition ...

The last label needs to be merged is `5`, which should be replaced by `4`.

I come up with this method: loop through `np.unique(data)` and check the count by `np.bincount(data)`. However, this method is slow if we have a large `data` array.

```
import random
data = np.concatenate(([0]*5, [1]*10, [2]*15, [3]*10, [4]*12, [5]*5))
random.Random(4).shuffle(data)

counts = np.bincount(data)

new_label = 0
count_num = 0

for label in np.unique(data):
    if count_num > 0:
        data[data==label] = label-1
    count_num += counts[label]
    
    if count_num >= 10:
        count_num = 0

    if label == np.unique(data)[-1] and counts[label] < 10:
        data[data==label] = label-1
```

```
array([2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0,
       4, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0,
       2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2])
```

Any ideas of this kind of merging data? Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of any numpy functions that help with this directly. Side note: maybe you could generate an array that fits your count requirements, and then shuffle that array to achieve randomness?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Actually this is a simplified example. The 1D array is output from a function, which returns some labels.

Comment: Please provide your full code and expected output for clarity. What you want seems to be a cumsum with restart. This cannot be efficiently vectorized. You must use a loop. If performance matters, use `numba`.

Comment: The speed should mostly depend on the number of unique values, what is it in the real dataset?

Comment: @mozway I have added the code. The length of my array is about 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is inefficient as you repeatedly slice the original array. Just run `np.unique` and get the counts **once**:

```
import random
data = np.concatenate(([0]*5, [1]*10, [2]*15, [3]*10, [4]*12, [5]*5))
random.Random(4).shuffle(data)

thresh = 10

count_sum = 0
label = 0
labels = []

vals, idx, cnt = np.unique(data, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
for i, c in enumerate(cnt, start=1):
    labels.append(label)
    if count_sum+c >= thresh:
        label = i
        count_sum = 0
    else:
        count_sum += c
# fix last labels
if cnt[-1] < thresh:
    labels = np.clip(labels, 0, labels[-1]-1)

out = vals[labels][idx]
```

Output:

```
array([2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0,
       4, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0,
       2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 4, 0, 2, 2])
```

##### timings

On 100k random values from 0-100

```
# original approach
863 ms ± 3.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# this solution
20.1 ms ± 673 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

On 1M random values from 0-1000

```
# original approach
# took too long, had to interrupt after 10 minutes

# this solution
525 ms ± 36.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very large variety of labels, Python loops should not be too much of a performance drain.   You may want to base your merging on labels that actually exist in the data (instead of increasing/decreasing by 1).  This can be achieved using +1/-1 on the current index rather than the label values.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 0, 4, 1, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2,
       1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 0, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 2, 
       3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2])


print("before:",np.bincount(data))

*counts, = map(list,zip(*np.unique(data, return_counts=True)))
minSize = 10
while any(c<minSize for _,c in counts):    # loop until all large enough
    for i in range(len(counts)-1,-1,-1):   # go trough indexes backward
        label,count = counts[i]
        if count >= minSize: continue          # merge small labels only
        if i>0:
            data[data==label] = counts[i-1][0] # merge with next label
            counts[i-1][1] += counts.pop(i)[1]
        elif i+1<len(counts):
            data[data==label] = counts[i+1][0] # merge with previous label
            counts[i+1][1] += counts[i][1]
            counts[i] = counts.pop(i+1)
        else:
            break                              # cannot merge to neighbour
        
print("after: ",np.bincount(data))
```

output:

```
before: [ 5 10 15 10 12  5]
after:  [ 0 15 15 10 17]
```